# Stripe API Request failed with status code 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

I am creating a website with next.js that has a shop with Stripe. The response if the api is 404.I creatr an enviroment to put the secret key, i have been told that is not a good practice, but I did not find other option to hold it that in an enviroment. I have Checked for typos in the route path or variable names and it seem that ports and host match between frontend and backend because info appears in the console. I am lost,can anyone have a clue what is happening?Thanks a lot!
This is Shop.js

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import bag from "pages/public/next.svg";
import { CreateCheckOutSession } from "../../components/Api/create-checkout-session";

function Shop() {
  // const [item, setItem] = useState({
  //   name: "Apple AirPods",
  //   description: "Latest Apple AirPods.",
  //   image: bag,
  //   quantity: 0,
  //   price: 999,
  // });
  const [item, setItem] = useState({
    name: "Apple AirPods",
    description: "Latest Apple AirPods.",
    image: "/path/to/bag.png",
    quantity: 0,
    image: bag,
    price: 999,
    // string instead of component
    // ...
  });
  const simpleItem = {
    name: item.name,
    description: item.description,
    price: item.price,
  };
  const changeQuantity = (value, number) => {
    setItem({ ...item, quantity: Math.max(0, value) });
  };

  const onQuantityPlus = () => {
    changeQuantity(item.quantity + 1);
  };

  const onQuantityMinus = () => {
    changeQuantity(item.quantity - 1);
  };
  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    changeQuantity(parseInt(e.target.value));
  };
  return (
    <div className="body-shop">
      <nav>
        <div className="arrow">
          <Link href="/">
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              width="16"
              height="16"
              fill="currentColor"
              class="bi bi-arrow-left-square"
              viewBox="0 0 16 16"
            >
              <path
                fill-rule="evenodd"
                d="M15 2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H2a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v12a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2zM0 2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2zm11.5 5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H5.707l2.147 2.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708.708L5.707 7.5H11.5z"
              />
            </svg>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="group">
          <Link href="/">Home</Link>
          <Link href="./About">About</Link>

          <Link href="./blog">Blog</Link>

          <Link href="./shop">Shop</Link>

          <Link href="./services">Personal styled Services</Link>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <h1>Shop</h1>
      <main>
        <div className="shadow-lg border rounded p-2 ">
          <Image src={item.image} width={300} height={150} />

          <h2 className="text-2xl">$ {item.price}</h2>
          <h3 className="text-xl">{item.name}</h3>
          <p className="text-gray-500">{item.description}</p>
          <p className="text-sm text-gray-600 mt-1">Quantity:</p>
          <div className="border rounded">
            <button
              onClick={onQuantityMinus}
              className="bg-blue-500 py-2 px-4 text-white rounded hover:bg-blue-600"
            >
              -
            </button>
            <input
              type="number"
              className="p-2"
              onChange={onInputChange}
              value={item.quantity}
            />
            <button
              onClick={onQuantityPlus}
              className="bg-blue-500 py-2 px-4 text-white rounded hover:bg-blue-600"
            >
              +
            </button>
          </div>
          <p>Total: ${item.quantity * item.price}</p>
          <button
            disabled={item.quantity === 0}
            onClick={CreateCheckOutSession}
            className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 text-white block w-full py-2 rounded mt-2 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-blue-100"
          >
            Buy
          </button>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Shop;
```

This is the checkout.js

```
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import axios from "axios";
import CreateStripeSession from "./create-stripe-session";
import { Shop } from "../../pages/important-pages/shop";
const publishableKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY;
const stripePromise = loadStripe(publishableKey);

export const CreateCheckOutSession = async () => {
  const stripe = await stripePromise;
  const checkoutSession = await axios.post(CreateStripeSession, {
    Shop: Shop,
  });

  // const checkoutSession = await axios.post(CreateStripeSession, Shop);
  const result = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    sessionId: checkoutSession.data.id,
  });
  if (result.error) {
    alert(result.error.message);
  }
};
```

This is createstripesession.js

```
export const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

async function CreateStripeSession(req, res) {
  const { item } = req.body;

  const redirectURL =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
      ? "http://localhost:3000"
      : "https://stripe-checkout-next-js-demo.vercel.app";

  const transformedItem = {
    price_data: {
      currency: "usd",
      product_data: {
        images: [item.image],
        name: item.name,
      },
      unit_amount: item.price * 100,
    },
    description: item.description,
    quantity: item.quantity,
  };

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    line_items: [transformedItem],
    mode: "payment",
    success_url: redirectURL + "?status=success",
    cancel_url: redirectURL + "?status=cancel",
    metadata: {
      images: item.image,
    },
  });

  res.json({ id: session.id });
}

export default CreateStripeSession;
```

Comment: What's the error message for the 404 ? What method returns it ?
Everything checks out when you log any of those variables ? (ie checkoutSession.data.id)

Also, worth mentioning that the `redirectToCheckout` function is considered legacy, Stripe recommends using a server redirect to the `Session.url` instead:  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSki6n502mk

Comment: Make sure the port you're using in the api call to your backend matches the port that your server is actually running on.